# Why strcmp doesn't work?

Tags: unix, process, popen, strcmp

The program works well.  It verifies if an argument is a file or a directory and it returns 1 or 2.  However, `strcmp` doesn't work and I don't know why.

Here is my code:

```c
#DEFINE N 100
int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {

FILE *fp;
char cmd[N];
char result[N];
int i;

for(i=1;i<argc;i++){
    pipe(c2p);
    if (fork()==0){
        //Running the shell script
            sprintf(cmd,"/home/flory/os/verif.sh %s", argv[i]);
            fp = popen(cmd, "r");
            fgets(result, N, fp);
            pclose(fp);
            printf("%s",result);    
            if (strcmp(result,"1")==0){
                     //DO SOMETHING
            }
}
```

Comment: Please copy-and-paste your *exact* code into the question. `#DEFINE` would be a syntax error; it's spelled `#define`.

Comment: `pipe(c2p);` What is c2p ? And why is it leaking?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to delete that part

Answer (score 0):

The variable `x` does not have a value yet.

Did you mean the following?

```
if (strcmp(result,"1")==0){
                 //DO SOMETHING
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from variable confusion in your question, please notice what happens with the trailing newline when reading a line of text. From linux man page fgets(3):

```
   fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream  and
   stores  them  into  the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an
   EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the  buffer.
   A '\0' is stored after the last character in the buffer.
```

I wrote a small program somewhat like yours:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  FILE      *fp;
  char bigbuf[10*1024];

  fp = popen("/bin/echo hello world", "r");
  fgets(bigbuf, sizeof bigbuf, fp);

  printf("length of bigbuf: %d\nlength of \"hello world\": %d\n", strlen(bigbuf), strlen("hello world"));
  exit(0);
}
```

Running it, I get the following output:

```
length of bigbuf: 12
length of "hello world": 11
```

Answer (score 0):

`result` has a terminating newline character since it has been read by `fgets()`, therefore, it would contain `"1\n"` (or possibly `"1\r\n"`, though that's unlikely), which is different from `"1"`.

You can delete the newline like this:

```
char *p;
if((p=strchr(result,'\n'))!=0) *p=0;
```

If your input contains CR you can remove them the same way.

Comment: Yes,I think that's the problem,but I don't know how to delete those characters...

Comment: Why would it contain `"1\r\n"` rather than `"1\n"`? The file patch `"/home/flory/os/verif.sh"` strongly implies a UNIX-like system. But even on Windows, if the stream is in text mode, any end-of-line markers will be automatically converted to single `'\n'` characters.

Comment: @Keith It depends on the line ending used by the process started by popen(). Unix programs normally use \n als line ending, Windows programs, however, use \r\n. So while verif.sh sounds like a unix shell script, no-one prevents it from generating Windows line endings. For example this might be the case if the output of verif.sh would also be used on Windows. So while unlikely I just mentioned \r for completeness.

Comment: That was the problem.I used strtok to truncate until "\n" and now my program is working